# Splice method does not remove array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript that has custom indexes, I created them like so:

```
var rand = event.timeStamp; //jquery on click event object

freeze_array[rand] = month + ',' + model_name + ',' + activity;
```

To remove the above element I have this:

```
freeze_array.splice(rand, 1);
```

But this does not remove the element as I can see it in my firebug dom object viewer. Here is an example of the array:

My indexes are in the form: `1283519490632` - too long to be an integer that is required by the splice method?

Thanks all for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, the index argument must be an integer. Maybe you can use an object that holds indices as follows:

```
var lastIndex=0; // that shall be global...
var pointer = {};

....

pointer[rand] = lastIndex;
++lastIndex;
```

Then use it as follows:

```
freeze_array = freeze_array.splice(pointer[rand], 1);
```

Comment: I have stopped using a large number and it works. Your method is good.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the index must be an integer. Your value is too large for a integer.
See at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

> index:    Required. An **integer** that
>   specifies at what position to
>   add/remove elements

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
delete freeze_array[ rand ];
```

Comment: This leaves a "hole" in the array, its not a complete removal.